# ValueError: Layer leaky_re_lu_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.convolutional.Conv3D'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to save the value of the convolution in a variable conv1 and then apply the value of conv1 in leaky relu activation function.

**Error :**

```
ValueError: Layer leaky_re_lu_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.convolutional.Conv3D'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv3D object at 0x7fc6312abe10>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

**Code :**

```
model = Sequential()

conv1 = Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), input_shape=(
    X.shape[1:]), border_mode='same')
conv2 = (LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))(conv1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing Keras [`Sequential`](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) and [`Functional`](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) APIs.

**Code with `Sequential` API:**

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv3D, LeakyReLU

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), input_shape=(X.shape[1:]), border_mode='same')
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))
```

**Code with `Functional` API:**

```python
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv3D, LeakyReLU, Input

inputs = Input(shape=X.shape[1:])
conv1 = Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), border_mode='same')(inputs)
relu1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(conv1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=relu1)
```